# Remove everything BEFORE and AFTER certain chars in a string

Tags: php, string

Good day,

I want to remove everything before and after a certain character sequence in a string.

E.g:

```
$string = 'TESTING<html>This is a string</html>ANOTHER TEST!!';
```

I want everything before `<html>` and after `</html>` to be removed, so that the string looks like this when I write it to a database:

```
<html>This is a string</html>
```

Important thing here is that `<html>` and `</html>` keep existing in the string.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: `'<html>'` is not a character, it's a string

Comment: OP is talking about a "character sequence".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// vars
$string = ' This is text before <html> and this is the text in between </html> And after there is some more text.. ';
$first = '<html>';
$last = '</html>';
// job
$start = stripos($string, $first); // first occurrence position 
$length = strripos($string, $last); // last occurrence position 
$newString = substr($string, $start, ($length-$start+strlen($last))); 
// output
var_dump($string,$start,$length,$newString);
```

Comment: _Curious ..._  Here is a working example http://3v4l.org/cVp49 (I don't know 3v4l.org before thx http://stackoverflow.com/users/3446241/typoheads)

Comment: @ Nolwennig Try this and you'll see what I mean: $string = '
This is text before <html> and this
is the text in between </html>

And after there is some more text..
';
$start = stripos($string, '<html>');    // first occurrence position
$length = strripos($string, '</html>'); // last occurrence position
$newString = substr($string, $start, $length);

var_dump($string,$start,$length,$newString);

Answer (score 5):

Can be done with a regular expression:

```
$str = 'TESTING<html>This is a string</html>ANOTHER TEST!!';
preg_match_all('/(<html>.*<\/html>)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1][0]);
```

For a multiline string, you have to add the modifier "m":

```
$str = 'TESTING<html>This is a string</html>ANOTHER TEST!!';
preg_match_all('/(<html>.*<\/html>)/m', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1][0]);
```

Comment: Don't know why but this is returning an empty array. Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )

Comment: Is your regular expression correkt? Here is a working example: http://3v4l.org/rUmBu

Comment: Do you have line breaks in your string? Then you have to add the modifier "m" to the regular expression. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yeah it's a fetched imap email, the update still returns an empty array.

Comment: That will be quite hard since the string that needs to be modified is an HTML email message fetched with the imap function. The string contains the HTML message but before the HTML, it also contains the receiving mailserver information which I'm trying to strip out.

Comment: And you are sure it contains an opening AND a closing HTML? Can you test the code with a test string like the one you provided in your question?

Comment: I'm very sure it contains an opening and closing HTML indeed. When I use your code just like it is, it works. But when I use your code and replacing $str with the e-mail message, it returns an empty array.

Comment: Then please post an example for the email string. Otherwise it's hard for us to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the posted answers, you can also use `strstr()` function to get the text before and after like;

```
$newstring = '<html>' . strstr($string, '<html>');
$newstring = strstr($newstring, '</html>', true) . '</html>';
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable sting